# Use file_put_contents as Upload Function?

Tags: php, file, file-upload

Can i also use file_put_contents($fileapp,$content,FILE_BINARY); to move uploaded files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can. But why not use [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://lv.php.net/move_uploaded_file) instead? This is generally considered to be safer than trying to access the path in `$_FILES`, since `move_uploaded_file()` does check if the file really is a file and if it was actually uploaded by the user.

If you can't use the `move_uploaded_file()`,  remember to call [`is_uploaded_file()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php) before you do the `file_put_contents()` call. Just for your own safety.

Comment: Because its a Class and i will use it somewhere else

Comment: Better to move the file first using the move_uploaded_file() before processing it with your class, so you make use of the safety checks of that function.